# jquery.transform.js Добавить префиксы

Tags: javascript, jquery, transform

Использую вот эту библеотеку
http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/index.html

Она пишет стили без префикса, как это испарить, чтобы она писала с префиусвми?

Пример

Вот так сейчас:

```
transform: scale(2);
```

А нужно вот так:

```
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
-ms-transform: scale(2);
transform: scale(2);
```

Может там есть какая-то настройка ?

Comment: а зачем тебе префиксы? Это раньше они были сильно нужны, сейчас это уже стандартные свойства

Comment: Для поддержки старых версий браузеров, разве они не нужны ?

Comment: посмотрите строки 28-31 https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/blob/master/jquery.transform2d.js

Comment: в данном случае transform что-то вроде метода, расширение jquery, а не css свойство.

Comment: 28-31 - я видел уже. А дальше что ?